# Origin of “Peace Through Superior Firepower”

Tags: etymology, idioms

*(I’m not sure if this is a valid question here†, as the phrase is arguably not common enough to be classed as a fixed expression.)*

Is there an ascertainable origin of **Peace Through Superior Firepower**?

It’s most probably a derivation of [“peace through strength”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_through_strength); there are citations of its first appearance in a [1988 episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Arsenal_of_Freedom) of *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_Through_Superior_Firepower) only knows a music DVD by this title, [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=peace%20through%20superior%20firepower) cites no quotes, and while [image seaches](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=Peace%20Through%20Superior%20Firepower) yield many gatling guns and patches with this slogan, [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Who-said-peace-through-superior-firepower) references a [removed Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Peace_Through_Superior_Firepower&type=revision&diff=242580508&oldid=210092520) (lack of sources) and [a 2001 novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March_to_the_Sea_(novel)) by John Ringo.

Even though this is perhaps impossible to answer definitively, it’d be interesting to know if say *Star Trek* writers first came up with this motto.

<sub>*† … or if it’s rather suitable at [scifi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek), asking: “Was* Star Trek *the first to come up with ~?”*</sub>

<sub>*‡ There are hundreds of thousands of web results, but incomparable [ngram graphs](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=peace%20through%20strength%2Cpeace%20through%20superior%20firepower&year_start=1924&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3#).*</sub>

Comment: [This book](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=7an9QXLFAjUC&pg=PA252&dq=Peace+Through+Superior+Firepower&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5lpW2usb4AhWeg4QIHYc_A2oQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=Peace%20Through%20Superior%20Firepower&f=false) was puublished 1981, and describes George Wallace's opinions...so that must mean going back to the 60s or 70s at least.

Comment: Strength is an attribute with unlimited application. Fire power is an attribute with a *very* limited application. If the fire-power phrase derived from the strength one, then it must have been done as a spoof.

Comment: It seems the distinction has long been recognised - "The phrase and the concept date to ancient times. Roman Emperor Hadrian (AD 76–138) is said to have sought "peace through strength or, **failing that, peace through threat.**"[2] Hadrian's Wall was a symbol of the policy.[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_through_strength

Comment: A notable example is [Ricco Frost's shirt](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Ricco_Frost?file=Frost%2527s_T-shirt_A2.png) in [Aliens (1986)](https://youtu.be/55a3rDrjdfI?t=48).

Answer (score 2):

> “Peace Through Superior Firepower”

In cases like this, [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Peace%20Through%20Superior%20Firepower&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true#) is sometimes helpful, however it is  not definitive.

[image]

As you can see, the earliest usage *in print* **in English** *as a phrase*  probably dates back to the late 1970s, but it may have been used as a shibboleth in jingoistic rhetoric  before that.

For example, I found a quote on [Google books](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=7TGMAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA135&dq=%22peace%20through%20superior%20firepower%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjOo8iR08b4AhWjZjABHeCZCXQQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22peace%20through%20superior%20firepower%22&f=false) going back to early 1970s referring to  [a bumper sticker issued by Brown's Magazine.](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=7TGMAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA135&dq=%22peace%20through%20superior%20firepower%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjOo8iR08b4AhWjZjABHeCZCXQQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22peace%20through%20superior%20firepower%22&f=false)

There may be more obscure references which are  only viewable on pay-walled sources.

Answer (score -1):

It's in Point Break (1991), in the van, right before the robbery.

The only other reference with this that I know of is Cradle of Flith's live DVD from 2005.

Comment: This is 20 years after the example given in the other answer.